# running synaptic remotely doesn't work

Tags: xorg, gtk, synaptic, dbus, remote-x-session

My Dell Inspiron 1100 (32-bit laptop) is running Ubuntu 17.04.  The machine has an Intel 82845GL graphics chip, which I cannot get to work.  I'll deal with that in a different post.

I'm trying to run `synaptic` on a different `$DISPLAY`, in my case, `localhost:10.0`, an ssh tunnel.  Note that I logged in (`ssh -Y`) as me and then ran `sudo` to get a root shell.

It sort of works, but every time I use a menu option, it misbehaves/fails to work, and I get a bunch of errors, as follows:

```
Script started on Wed 26 Jul 2017 07:26:03 PM PDT
stupid ~ 110# synaptic

** (synaptic:1390): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-L39Ey9ADLX: Connection refused
(synaptic:1390): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/bennett/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_get_preferred_height_for_width: assertion 'width >= 0' failed
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content width -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node menuitem, owner GtkMenuItem)
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content height -6 (allocation 1, extents 4x3) while allocating gadget (node menuitem, owner GtkMenuItem)
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content width -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node menuitem, owner GtkMenuItem)
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content height -6 (allocation 1, extents 4x3) while allocating gadget (node menuitem, owner GtkMenuItem)
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content width -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node menuitem, owner GtkMenuItem)
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content height -6 (allocation 1, extents 4x3) while allocating gadget (node menuitem, owner GtkMenuItem)
(synaptic:1390): Gtk-WARNING **: Negative content width -11 (allocation 1, extents 6x6) while allocating gadget (node separator, owner GtkSeparatorMenuItem)
...
```

I see similar behavior with other applications running remotely.  What am I missing?  Programs like `xterm` seem to work fine.

Why can't it connect to the dbus?  Is that what's killing it?

Comment: What if you run `sudo synaptic`?

Comment: What is your host system? What other programs don't work? Can you please provide more specific information as to what triggers this crash (like any menu option, only menus on the taskbar)?

Comment: I didn't try running `sudo synaptic` since I was already running as root.

Comment: The host system is, sadly, Cygwin/X.  It's whatever is current.  

    Welcome to the XWin X Server
    Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
    Release: 1.19.2.0
    OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 heimdall 2.8.2(0.313/5/3) 2017-07-12 10:58 x86_64
    OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (Win64)
    Package: version 1.19.2-1 built 2017-03-09

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.

Comment: If I click on the `file` (or any other) menu, it yields those errors.  Other widgets cause it, too.  I'll see if I can isolate a simpler program.

Comment: The menus on `gnome-terminal` don't work, either, but it seems to be better at hiding the GTK errors.  That is, the menus don't work, as they don't in `synaptic`, but `gnome-terminal` seems to `fork()` and not print any errors to `stderr`.